# Two NIC using computer as switch

Tags: linux, networking, router

```
                                         |====|
       FiOS           Switch/LB6M        |    |
   [_...__...°]------>[_...__...°] ----->|____| Desktop / Ubuntu
         |  |    W1      | | |      W2   
         |  |            | | |    
         |  |            | | |
         v  v            v v v
  [wifi/other]          [.....°]
                        [.....°]
                        [.....°] Cluster / Ubuntu
```

Above is my current configuration. FiOS is acting as DHCP server for all. Desktop, cluster nodes and others are using same network. 10.0.0.xxx

I am trying to connect W1 to the desktop so that i am able to turn on the switch only when the cluster is running and keep off other time.

W2 and all connection from Switch to Cluster nodes are 10GbE.

I need the nodes on cluster to be able to access internet from FiOS for updates as well as desktop be able to connect to nodes. For the speed, most of the data flows between each other over 10GbE and switch. I will be able to assign static ip to switch, nodes on cluster and the desktop.

I want to avoid parallel wire like W1 going from FiOS to Desktop. I am thinking of adding 4 hub un-managed switch to fork W1 to the switch and desktop would like to avoid that if i can use desktop as transparent port for switch to rest of the network.

Will there be any performance penalty on data transfer if using new switch or desktop in between.

I am fairly new in advance networking, but have fair linux experience. Can you please suggest any pointers, terms that i need to look at or any other suggestion.

---

SOLVED as per @TOOGAM suggestion. Configured /etc/network/interfaces as follows in a case if anyone else might need it.:

```
iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth2 inet manual
allow-hotplug eth2

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0 eth2
    address 10.0.0.235
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    dns-search google.com
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    hwaddress ether 40:16:7e:76:f5:F6
```

Installed bridge-utils as `apt-get install bridge-utils`

Comment: Thank you. Bridging solved the issue. I was hopping through NAT, DHCP server and other complexities. Simple configuration of bridge interface on network/interfaces worked as intended.

Comment: (My answer was initially a comment, which user530302's comment was responding to.  I removed the comment to reduce redundant text after I made the actual answer, which is only a slight elaboration of the comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you please suggest any pointers, terms that i need to look at or any other suggestion.

If you want to pass on Layer 2 network traffic, which is essentially what a switch accomplishes, then the generic term for this is called "bridging". (Well, a switch may be a bit more complicated than a bridge, thanks to using CAM tables.) I would expect a Linux system can perform bridging, as long as the drivers are sufficient (which I would guess would probably not be a problem). So that is one term you may wish to look into. "How to bridge?"

> Will there be any performance penalty on data transfer if using new switch or desktop in between?

In theory, dedicated equipment is specialized and may provide better performance. Reality doesn't always match theory.  Of course, this change shouldn't end up slowing down overall communications if the communications also involve another part of the network which is slower.

The actual answer can vary based on details like what hardware/drivers are used, what software is used, how it is configured, etc.  So there isn't just a simple single answer that will accurately fit all scenarios.  I would just suggest trying it.  If performance is unacceptable, try asking another question which is specific about model numbers/etc.